# PHP Retrieve Database Value

Tags: php, database

So i have this so far..

```
if(isset($_POST['Decrypt']))
{
    $dbinary = strtoupper($_POST['user2']);
    $sqlvalue = "SELECT `value` FROM `license` WHERE `binary` = '$dbinary'";
    $dvalue = mysql_query($sqlvalue) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

I have a field where the user enters a binary code which was encrypted. (The encrypt part works). This is supposed to retrieve the value from the database. When ever i do it, instead of the value showing up, it says "Resource id #11".

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection. It is highly recommended to switch from the now deprecated `mysql_*()` API to a more modern one like PDO supporting parameterized queries.  [This tutorial will help you get started](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: I plan on doing that soon, but for the time being I only use it for personal matters, and it is on my personal server. It is not accessable by anyone but me, and no one knows about it.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your quoting. In fact, everything looks right so far.

The thing is, right now $dvalue is just a resource to the SQL database. You have to fetch the contents with one more line:

```
$dvalue = mysql_fetch_array($dvalue);
```

In the future, you might want to start using PDO or MySQLi instead of the mysql functions, because those are deprecated as of 5.5.0. The advantage of PDO and MySQLi is that they offer security from SQL Injection, which is when users run their own SQL code by inputting something like `x'; DROP TABLE members; --`.

Comment: ...after which you'll have an array so be sure to access the column you need as an array key `$dvalue['value']`, otherwise, you'll get `Array` as output.

Comment: Ok so Michael you were right, "array" did come up. However, when i entered `$dvalue['value']` like you said, i got this error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/u923860750/public_html/cpanel/cpanel.php on line 31

Comment: oh wait, that was because i did not put a ; after the line. But when i put the semicolon, again it shows `Array`

Comment: You can't echo an array directly to the user. To display the contents of an array for testing purposes, use `var_dump($dvalue);`. Otherwise you must echo a single item of the array, i.e. `echo $dvalue['binary'];`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `mysql_` functions anymore. They are [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

That being said, you are only running the query, and not retrieving any results. You will have to call a function like [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) to get data from the resource ID that `mysqli_query` will return.

My advice is to go back to the tutorials and documentation and try again with one of these other extensions. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Read this page: [W3 Schools page on MySQL select useage](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp). Basically $dvalue is a result set id and you'll need to actually fetch the array out of the database in another step. Also, mysql_* functions are deprecated. Lookup and use the mysqli_* functions instead.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dvalue))
{
  echo $row['value'];
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Please link to official PHP documentation instead of w3schools, which is widely regarded to be of very low quality (full of SQL injection vulns, etc)